# How do I "automate" my program to run each object when I call it

Tags: javascript

What I want to fix is to call one of the objects names inside the function and it should print the information, I have tried different methods but can't seem to find the a good fix to automate it.

```
const usAlbania = {
    name: "United States of Albania",
    artist: "Mc Kresha, Lyrical Son, Lluni",
    type: "Hip-Hop",
    songs: "23",
    year: "2019"
};

const ybnMixtape = {
    name: "YBN Mixtape",
    artist: "YBN Nahmir, YBN Almighty Jay, YBN Cordae",
    type: "Rap & Hip-hop",
    songs: "17",
    year: "2018"
};

const astroWorld = {
    name: "Astro World",
    artist: "Travis Scott",
    type: "Rap",
    songs: "13",
    year: "2018"
};

const albums = {
    usAlbania: usAlbania,
    ybnMixtape: ybnMixtape,
    astroWorld: astroWorld
}

function albumShow () {
    const html = `
        <p><img src="images/USA.jpg" height="200"></p>
        <p class="albumName">Album Name: ${albums}</p>
        <p class="artist">Artist: ${albums}</p>
        <p class="type">Grenre: ${albums}</p>
        <p class="songs">Album Songs: ${albums}</p>
        <p class="year">Album Year: ${albums}</p>
    `
    const showAlbumInfo = document.querySelector('.albumInfo');
    showAlbumInfo.innerHTML = html;
}

albumShow()
```

Comment: Put the objects in an array and do a random grab of an item

Comment: What do you mean by `'run' an object`?

Comment: What I mean is when I call the function albumShow() inside the parentheses I want to put the album name and it should print the album info.

Answer (score 0):

```
const albums = [{
    name: "United States of Albania",
    artist: "Mc Kresha, Lyrical Son, Lluni",
    type: "Hip-Hop",
    songs: "23",
    year: "2019"
},
{
    name: "YBN Mixtape",
    artist: "YBN Nahmir, YBN Almighty Jay, YBN Cordae",
    type: "Rap & Hip-hop",
    songs: "17",
    year: "2018"
},
{
    name: "Astro World",
    artist: "Travis Scott",
    type: "Rap",
    songs: "13",
    year: "2018"
}];

function albumShow (albumName) {
    const album = albums.find(album => {
        album.name === albumName
    });
    const html = `
        <p><img src="images/USA.jpg" height="200"></p>
        <p class="albumName">Album Name: ${album.name}</p>
        <p class="artist">Artist: ${album.artist}</p>
        <p class="type">Grenre: ${album.type}</p>
        <p class="songs">Album Songs: ${album.songs}</p>
        <p class="year">Album Year: ${album.year}</p>
    `
    const showAlbumInfo = document.querySelector('.albumInfo');
    showAlbumInfo.innerHTML = html;
}

albumShow("Astro World")//change the name
```

Comment: I don't want it to be a random pick, but the one of the objects I choose.

Comment: How do you plan on "choosing" one? In the code, or through ui?

Comment: I plan when calling the function to put inside album name and should print it.

Comment: @bySteve checkout the revised answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it:

```js
let aryAlbums = [];
const usAlbania = {
    name: "United States of Albania",
    artist: "Mc Kresha, Lyrical Son, Lluni",
    type: "Hip-Hop",
    songs: "23",
    year: "2019"
};
aryAlbums.push(usAlbania);

const ybnMixtape = {
    name: "YBN Mixtape",
    artist: "YBN Nahmir, YBN Almighty Jay, YBN Cordae",
    type: "Rap & Hip-hop",
    songs: "17",
    year: "2018"
};
aryAlbums.push(ybnMixtape);

const astroWorld = {
    name: "Astro World",
    artist: "Travis Scott",
    type: "Rap",
    songs: "13",
    year: "2018"
};
aryAlbums.push(astroWorld);

function albumShow(album)
{
  return `
    <p><img src="http://www.neartalk.com/ss/usaCD.jpg" height="200"></p>
    <p class="albumName">Album Name: ${album.name}</p>
    <p class="artist">Artist: ${album.artist}</p>
    <p class="type">Grenre: ${album.type}</p>
    <p class="songs">Album Songs: ${album.songs}</p>
    <p class="year">Album Year: ${album.year}</p>
  `;
}

let aryHTML = aryAlbums.map(albumShow);

let allHTML = aryHTML.join("\n");
document.body.innerHTML = allHTML;
```

Comment: @bySteve : You could call any of the objects you created using the `albumShow` function above. I also put the objects your created into array, so that I could call `albumShow` on each on your object using the built-in [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. However, you could have done this manually for each one. For example, `albumShow(ybnMixtape)` returns the html for the object you named ybnMixtape.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const usAlbania = { key: "usalbania", name: "United States of Albania", artist: "Mc Kresha, Lyrical Son, Lluni", type: "Hip-Hop", songs: "23", year: "2019" };
```

Add one more field like "key" into each object and then push all your object to array one by one or through looping...

While fetching the data from array use "filter" or "find" or "grep" keyword to get your object from the list...

**For instance :**

```
var result =
ArrayObject.filter(x=> x.key === "usalbania" )[];
```